# Iterating over a styled component in REACT produces warning "Over 200 classes were generated for component"

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, styled-components

I'm new to React and am trying to animate some elements from an array using the ReShake.js library.  Here's my code:

```
import { ShakeHorizontal } from 'reshake'
const state = {
    invalidWordSubmitted: true,
}
const isInvalidWordSubmitted = () => {
  return state.invalidWordSubmitted ? '.invalidWordSubmitted' : ''
```

}

// here is the bit that I think is causing the problem:

```
           <div id="gameBoard" className="gameBoard">         
        {board.map((row, rowNumber) =>
          row.map((letter, colNumber) => (
            <span
              key={colNumber}
            >
              <ShakeHorizontal trigger={`${isInvalidWordSubmitted()}`}>
              {letter}
              </ShakeHorizontal>
            </span>
          ))
        )}
      </div>
```

It works ok, but there is serious lag in the browser, and the console shows me the following warning: `react_devtools_backend.js:4045 Over 200 classes were generated for component styled.div with the id of "sc-bdvvtL"`

Should I be adding unique ids to each of the iterated `<ShakeHorizontal>` components?
I couldn't find anything in the docs: https://github.com/elrumordelaluz/reshake/tree/master/src

Comment: That `className={``${getCellStyles...` rings me a bell. Provide `getCellStyle` code

Comment: Btw is all this ``${}`` string casting sintax that you use intended?

Comment: Given that you are rendering a component for every element of a two-dimensional array, it's not hard to see how this could create some performance issues if the array is large.

Comment: The array isn't that big, 6 rows of 5 elements. My gut is telling me that there needs to be some sort of unique id added to each of the elements.  This is the html of the Functional Component `<div dur="300" class="sc-bdvvtL eFINMF">F</div>`

Comment: edit: I don't think it's the getCellStyles function that is causing my issue,  It is definitely the <ShakeHorizontal> Component. I'll update my code example to make ti clearer

Comment: Is there any impact/change if the `trigger` prop is removed from `<ShakeHorizontal>` component?

Comment: If I remove the trigger prop the animation runs on hover (default) but there is no change to the performance difficulties.  I actually gave up with this library and wrote what I needed in vanilla css and it worked..

Answer (score 0):

todo it inline style like here I did  for my clock component

```
<div className="hourHand" style={{ transform: `rotate(${hour}deg)` }}></div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).